# Calling a method from containing class from a method in the inner class

Tags: c++, oop, nested, inner-classes

I have two classes:

class `My_package`, which have methods that are just for sending stuff to the hardware and class `Automation_algorithm`, that perform all the algorithm that process `my data`.

So what I thought I should do is to have an instance of class `Automation_algorithm` as a member of my class `My_package`.

But at some point, I execute a method from the class `Automation_algorithm`, and in this method, I check if a certain condition is met, and if it is met, I would like to use a method from the class `My_package` to send an acceleration command to my system. But how do I call a method `accelerate()` from the "containing class".

For clarity, I have something like

```
class My_package
{
public :
void accelerate(double a,double t);
...

private:
Automation_algorithm my_algorithm;
...
};

class Automation_algorithm
{
public:
void method1(); // I want to call accelerate(a,t) from here!!!
...
private:
...
};
```

I thank you for your responses and taking in consideration that I am not a c++ champ.

Answer (score 1):

Using Bridge Design Pattern, here's a snippet:

```
class My_package
{
public:
    My_package();
    void accelerate(double a, double t);
    struct impl;  // declaring the implementation 
private:
    Automation_algorithm my_algorithm;  
    std::unique_ptr<impl> impl_; // implementation is defined here
};

struct My_package::impl {
    impl() {}
    void accelerate(double a, double t) {/* */} // implementation is defined here
};

My_package::My_package() : impl_( new impl() ) {}
void My_package::accelerate(double a, double t) { impl_->accelerate(a, t); }

class Automation_algorithm
{
public:
    Automation_algorithm();
    void method1(void)
    {
        double a,t;
        impl_->accelerate(a, t);
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<struct My_package::impl> impl_;
};

Automation_algorithm::Automation_algorithm() : impl_(new My_package::impl()) {}
```

Comment: Why do you define imp1 with a structure rather than with a class?
I never saw the bridge pattern or any pattern, could you just explain what makes this a bridge pattern?

Comment: Why is accelerate() a method of the class My_package, but also a method of the structure imp1 of that package?

Comment: Bridge pattern breaks the implementation from the interface, by slight adaptation the implementation was made common for both classes. Implementation could be hidden whereas the interface part will be exposed, so a struct will suffice for impl. Proxy Pattern may also work here.

Comment: But what would be the "bridge class" here?

Comment: Both the classes provide only interfaces and they are public, the actual implementation is defined in struct impl, hence the name bridge pattern.

Comment: But if I define accelerate() in the structure, I cannot call the data members of My_package from the accelerate() core no?

Comment: Imagine you want to share an object without exposing the functionality. Your shared object will contain only function declarations and the rest ( data + private members) will be handled by the implementation. Looks clean to the other  users. In this case, to avoid code duplication ( as in accelerate), the implementation is shared with the interface objects.